# Using the Fundamental Theorem for Finitely-Generated Modules over a PID

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have been given the following question:

> Let $V = \mathbb{R}^6$, viewed as an $\mathbb{R}[x]$-module by letting $x$ act as multiplication by the matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -16\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 8\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Express $V$ as a direct sum of cyclic submodules using the structure theorem for finitely-generated modules over a PID. Find the minimal polynomial and Jordan canonical form of $A$. How many non-isomorphic $\mathbb{R}[x]$-modules on $\mathbb{R}^6$ arise from linear transformations with the same minimal polynomial as $A$.

I recognize $A$ is already in rational canonical form, and the minimal polynomial is $(x-2)^2(x+2)^2$, and the characteristic polynomial is $(x-2)^4(x+2)^2$. I also found the Jordan canonical form.

My question is with the first and last part of this question. How do I write $V$ as a direct sum of cyclic submodules this way? Using my notes, I think it might be: $ V \simeq  \mathbb{R}[x]/((x-2)^2) \bigoplus \mathbb{R}[x]/((x-2)^2(x+2)^2) $ but I am not sure this is correct.

And for the last part, I don't understand how to determine what it's asking. I think the answer might be three, knowing the minimal and characteristic polynomials, but I am not sure how to calculate this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To express $V$ as a sum of cyclic submodules, you  want to find a rational canonical basis; what you write does not express $V$ as a sum of cyclic submodules, it gives the isomorphism type (slightly different).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How do I find a rational canonical basis?

Comment: $ \mathbb{R}[x]/(f(x))$ is a cyclic module so it suffices to realize the isomorphism $V\to ..$, the Jordan normal form does that. Also $(x-2)^2,(x+2)^2$ are comaximal so you can decompose $V\cong R[x]/(x-2)^2\oplus R[x]/(x-2)^2\oplus R[x]/(x+2)^2$ (to obtain the irreducible, thus cyclic, submodules)